# Mongodb FDW Extension for postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, postgres-fdw

Can i get proper documentation for MongoDB foreign data wrapper extension installation For PostgreSQL ? Will it support AWS RDS and Aurora?

I'm trying to create a MongoDB foreign data wrapper extension from PostgreSQL db to MongoDB. But i'm not getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far RDS and Aurora do not support Mongo FDW, the official documentation of this FDW is [here](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw)